# python class for graph data structure contain add edge method i find it complex to understand

Tags: python, data-structures, graph

I'm learning python and this an exercise, I'm trying to build graph data.

```
class Vertex:
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
    self.edges = {}

  def add_edge(self, vertex, weight = 0):
    self.edges[vertex] = weight

  def get_edges(self):
    return list(self.edges.keys())
class Graph:
  def __init__(self, directed = False):
    self.graph_dict = {}
    self.directed = directed

  def add_vertex(self, vertex):
    self.graph_dict[vertex.value] = vertex

  def add_edge(self, from_vertex, to_vertex, weight = 0):
    self.graph_dict[from_vertex.value].add_edge(to_vertex.value, weight) 
    if not self.directed:
      self.graph_dict[to_vertex.value].add_edge(from_vertex.value, weight)
```

In graph class in `add_edge` method i find the following code complex and I don't understand how it works.

```py
self.graph_dict[from_vertex.value].add_edge(to_vertex.value, weight)
```

Comment: you can write it in to lines: get some vertex from ditcionary `vertex = self.graph_dict[from_vertex.value]` and add new edge to this vertex `vertex.add_edge(to_vertex.value, weight)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what make you problem but you can write it in two lines

```
#get some vertex from ditcionary
some_vertex = self.graph_dict[from_vertex.value] 

#and add new edge to this vertex 
some_vertex.add_edge(to_vertex.value, weight)
```

Comment: Even if you don't know that's was helpfull . I understand it now . Thank you .